# Conflicting performance results of random number generators

Tags: python, performance, numpy, random, timeit

Coming from my [question on Code-Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189168/simulating-surname-convergence-in-a-population), some analysis of the performance of random number generating libraries was done, specifically python and numpy's `random` facilities. One would assume that there would be some differences of performance on different machines, but the overall conclusion would be the same, `x` is faster than `y`. However, that is not the case.

In [Oscar Smith's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189173/13738), he performed a test, and got the following results, run on Ubuntu, Python 2.7 and 3.6, NumPy 1.14.1:

```
timeit.timeit('rand(0,1000)', setup='from numpy.random import uniform as rand')
0.7485988769913092
timeit.timeit('rand(0,1000)', setup='from random import uniform as rand')
0.2676771300029941
```

---

I performed the same test, and got opposite results, run on RHEL 7.4, Python 2.7.5, NumPy 1.7.1:

```
timeit.timeit("rand(0, 1000)", setup="from numpy.random import uniform as rand")
0.1250929832458496
timeit.timeit("rand(0, 1000)", setup="from random import uniform as rand")
0.47645998001098633
```

I would expect that these values would be different, but proportionally the same, ie he would get `0.5, 0.1`, and I would get `0.25, 0.05`. However, we got direct opposite results. What's going on here? And if possible, which library is officially considered faster?

An interesting sidenote, run within an online interpreter https://repl.it/languages/python3, native python is faster:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux


   import timeit
   import numpy
   numpy.__version__
=> '1.14.1'
   timeit.timeit('rand(0,1000)', setup='from numpy.random import uniform as rand')
=> 2.416280833000201
   timeit.timeit('rand(0,1000)', setup='from random import uniform as rand')
=> 1.0206557700003032
```

Comment: What operating system was each scan performed on? What versions of Python were used?

Comment: Also, what versions of NumPy?

Comment: RHEL 7.4, python 2.7.5, numpy 1.7.1

Comment: BTW, I'm getting 1.9424261669996667 and 4.202998832999583 respectively (yep, really slow). iPad running iOS 9, Python 3.6.1, NumPy 1.8.0

Comment: @ForceBru Thank god I'm not running my sim on an iPad then.

Comment: Oscar [reports](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189168/simulating-surname-convergence-in-a-population/189173#comment361738_189173) ubuntu, 2.7 and 3.6, 1.14.1

Comment: Using linux python 3 on an old slow 2 core notebook I got 4.8 (numpy) and 1.5 (python) which is proportionally similar to you. I wonder if number of cores matter.

Comment: 1.7.1 is really old.

Comment: @user2357112 And that's considering we just "upgraded" to RHEL 7.4 like a week ago, which I assume updated some of my python things.

Comment: @Drise, `pip install --upgrade numpy`

Comment: @ForceBru Not on a machine I don't control the config of. :/ Also, even worse `bash: pip: command not found`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on a really old NumPy version, NumPy 1.7.1. `numpy.random` has grown more complex since then.

For example, comparing the [1.14.1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.1/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1215) and [1.7.1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.1/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1095) implementations of `numpy.random.uniform`, the 1.14.1 implementation involves a lock and does extra work to support array-likes for `low` and `high`. 1.7.1 doesn't do that.

`numpy.random.randint` (which you used in your Code Review question) has grown more complex too. Comparing the [1.14.1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.1/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L910) and [1.7.1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.1/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L812) implementations, the 1.14.1 implementation includes a lock, dynamic dispatch by dtype, and substantial use of Python-level APIs, all of which add per-call overhead. The 1.7.1 implementation is much more direct.

Comment: Yes, but why would that result in the numpy winning on one machine by 3x and losing on another by 3x.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: Fluke. The ratio isn't as exactly reversed as it might look; in Oscar's test, NumPy takes 2.8 times as long, and in Drise's test, `random` takes 3.8 times as long.

Comment: @user2357112 I mean, that still seems like a decent enough variance warranting further investigation, hence why we're here.

Comment: @Drise: I've explained why `numpy.random.randint` has more per-call overhead than it used to have. That's where the slowdown is coming from. The runtime ratio of `numpy.random.randint` and `random.randint` kind of looks exactly reversed at first glance, but it's not, and there's nothing deeper that would push for an exact reversal.

Comment: @user2357112 I ran the test in an online interpreter and it looks like it's supporting your conclusion. A 2.4x speed up using python over numpy when using numpy 1.14.1.